# Matrix, and Differential Equation Solution Verification

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I given the following system:\begin{equation}\mathbf{X'}=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & \frac14\\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{X}\end{equation}
Every variable in the system is a matrix. I am then given that $\mathbf{X}$ is a column matrix.\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}-e^{-\frac{3t}2} \\2e^{-\frac{3t}2}\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & \frac14\\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-e^{-\frac{3t}2} \\2e^{-\frac{3t}2}\end{pmatrix}\end{align}
The excerise involves in verifing that $\mathbf{X}$ is a solution to this linear system. I am wondering if my steps are correct in assessing the problem that is given at hand.

### My Steps

\begin{equation}\begin{pmatrix}\frac32e^{-\frac{3t}2}\\ -3e^{-\frac{3t}{2}}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-\frac{3t}2}+\frac12e^{-\frac{3t}2}\\ -e^{-\frac{3t}2}-2e^{-\frac{3t}2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac32e^{-\frac{3t}2}\\ -3e^{-\frac{3t}{2}}\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}
$\because$ the LHS equals the RHS $\therefore$ the solution proposed by $\mathbf{X}$ is a valid one.

Comment: Looks good to me ...Your steps are correct. Good job. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks correct to me.
$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}-e^{-\frac{3t}2} \\2e^{-\frac{3t}2}\end{pmatrix}&=\begin{pmatrix}-1 & \frac14\\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-e^{-\frac{3t}2} \\2e^{-\frac{3t}2}\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$
You can also write it this way:
$$\begin{align}\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} \frac{d}{dt}e^{-\frac{3t}2}=&\begin{pmatrix}-1 & \frac14\\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}- 1\\2\end{pmatrix}e^{-\frac{3t}2}\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}-\frac 32\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}=&\begin{pmatrix}-1 & \frac14\\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}- 1\\2\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$
So that you only have matrices with numbers !!

Comment: You can just like manipulate the derivative on that matrices?

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky here you can simplify because you have the same exponential in each element of the matrice. You factorize the exponential. Like any constant.